# What does this datetime comparison evaluate to in MSSQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Have deleted some records by filtering with this condition `AddedOn < '2021-03-11 00:00:00'`

Intention is to remove everything before `2021-03-11`.

However, I realise there's still 2 records with AddedOn value of `2021-03-10 23:25:xx` left.

So what did the comparison expression actually evaluate to?

Comment: They were probably added after you deleted the data.  Alternative, the column *could* be a string -- if you have a malformed data model -- and there could be a problem with the string comparison.  Or, there could be a timezone problem if the column is `datetimeoffset`.

Comment: Even *if* you're storing the values as a `varchar` (a major design flaw, by the way), `'2021-03-10 23:25:xx'` is *less than* `'2021-03-11 00:00:00'`, so I suspect that these rows were not in the table when you processed the `DELETE`.

Comment: If you run the statement and the rows are still there, then post a full [mre].

Comment: On a side note, consider using [DATEFROMPARTS (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefromparts-transact-sql) instead of string literals for dates. If you have `set dateformat dmy;` active then your datetime string would be interpreted as 3-Nov-2021 00:00:00 AM which is something you definitely wouldn't want.